# ¿Como unir elementos comunes y consecutivos de un array en Objective-C?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

soy nuevo por aqui, espero me podáis ayudar con una duda que me a surgido para un proyecto de chat que estoy realizando.

El problema es el siguiente, yo obtengo todo el historial de mensajes de un chat desde PHP en un json y lo paso a un NSMutableArray y lo muestro en una TableView, en un lado los mensajes de uno y al otro lado los del otro. Si una misma persona manda muchos mensajes consecutivos, queda muy mal, ya que en cada mensaje se muestra la foto del usuario y se hace repetitivo.

Lo que quiero hacer es, en el array unir todos los mensajes que pertenecen a la misma persona y que se han mandado consecutivos, para que se muestren todos juntos con una sola foto de la persona que los manda, al igual que hace WhatsApp y otras plataformas.

El array recibe los valores (idUserA, idUserB, fotoA, fotoB, mensaje y userQueEnvia)

Quiero juntar los mensajes en el cual el "userQueEnvia" es el mismo y consecutivo.

Me podeis orientar un poco, ya que no consigo nada al respecto.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Antes que todo bienvenido Jano :). Te sugiero que leas  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que veas cual es la forma de cuestionar aquí en la cominudad. Bien, ¿Podrías compartir tu código? tu pregunta no se entiende muy bien, si especificas tu problema y compartes tu código es más fácil para los usuarios ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0):

te sugiero refinar un poco tu modelo de clases. En casos así conviene harto apoyarse de algún ORM como Realm https://realm.io/ el cual es una herramienta poderosa para que el UITableView se alimente directamente de la base de datos mediante consultas. Puedes hacer consultas filtradas por usuario (Entendiendo que puedes tener una entidad usuario con alguna relación uno a muchos a otra entidad de mensaje) e incluso ordenarlos por NSDate.

Luego es cosa de extender la clase UITableViewCell a las entidades mensaje con las que trabajes.

También con Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/ podrías tener resultados interesantes, pero tendrías que meter mano también a tu Backend.

Espero que la información te sea buena guía.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, al final dandole vueltas a mi duda, he sacado una solución, que no se si será la mejor, pero hace lo que necesitaba. Os dejo el código por si a alguien le puede servir:

```
NSMutableArray *tablaMensajes = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tablaMensajes = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"datos"];
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSMutableDictionary *mensaje in tablaMensajes) {
        if (temp.count == 0) [temp addObject:mensaje];
        else {
            if ([[mensaje objectForKey:@"actual"]isEqualToString:[[temp lastObject]objectForKey:@"actual"]]) {
                NSMutableDictionary *cambiar = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [cambiar setValue:[mensaje objectForKey:@"actual"] forKey:@"actual"];
                [cambiar setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", [[temp lastObject]objectForKey:@"mensaje"], [mensaje objectForKey:@"mensaje"]] forKey:@"mensaje"];
                [temp removeLastObject];
                [temp addObject:cambiar];
            } else [temp addObject:mensaje];
        }
    }
tablaMensajes = temp;
```